# Is it possible to model a compound pendulum without differential equations?

Tags: physics-engine

I am working through the book "The Nature of Code" and in one chapter (http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-3-oscillation/) it goes over modeling a pendulum. It has an exercise at the end that tells you to create two pendulums and link the pivot point of one to the bottom of the other creating a compound pendulum but it then mentions that the model would be physically inaccurate and requires differential equations to model accurately. My question is wouldn't it be possible to model a compound pendulum by just calculating the force of tension and gravity acting on each bob and then using those forces to calculate the acceleration, velocity, and position?

Comment: I would say because the differential equation is the exact representation of the pendulums movement, from a purely mathematical perspective, you would be doing it wrong.

Comment: Would the method of calculating the net force work or at least be a good approximation?

Comment: There must be some kind of confusion "calculating the force of tension and gravity and use them to calculate acceleration, velocity and position" is exactly doing integration to solve a differential equation.